# The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm building a website using AWS S3.

When I use AWS Toolkit, it works fine, but I can't use the same toolkit on an online host, so I tried using AWS Credentials file, I made sure it's the same `AWS_ACCESS_ID` and the same `SECRET_KEY` I used with the Toolkit but it still gives me the same error.

**Stack Trace**

```
AmazonS3Exception: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.]

Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleException(IExecutionContext executionContext, HttpErrorResponseException exception) +580
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ExceptionHandler1.Handle(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception) +76

Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.ProcessException(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception) +197
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +73
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +16
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +27
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +16
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Signer.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +25
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +16
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +29
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +16
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +132
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +16
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +27
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +16
Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3KmsHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +29
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +16
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointResolver.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +27
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +16
Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3PostMarshallHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +29
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +16
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Marshaller.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +25
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +16
Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3PreMarshallHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +29
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +16
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +27
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +16
Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ExceptionHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +58
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +16
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +56
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +16
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +119
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RuntimePipeline.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) +26
Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient.Invoke(TRequest request, IMarshaller`2 marshaller, ResponseUnmarshaller unmarshaller) +190
Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.ListObjects(ListObjectsRequest request) +44
DownloadFile.GetFoldersOnly(String folder) in c:\Users\Hamzastein\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\PhotoGallery\DownloadFile.aspx.cs:110
DownloadFile.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Hamzastein\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\PhotoGallery\DownloadFile.aspx.cs:17
System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +678
```

Comment: You are not using the access key that you think you are using, or it's not actually a valid access key, or you're connecting to a region for which the access key is not valid (e.g. using public region credentials against the AWS govcloud region).

Comment: I called it again using netSDKFile.ListProfiles() and profile.Options.AccessKey, compared it with the access key I used, they are typically the same, and I'm sure about the region as I use the region specified to the bucket.

Comment: Check if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051477/the-aws-access-key-id-does-not-exist-in-our-records

Comment: I tried it before, still the same.