# How to resolve S3ServiceException: Invalid Access Key ID in Airflow while attempting unload from Redshift

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow

I'm writing a DAG that makes use of [RedShiftToS3Operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/operators/redshift_to_s3_operator.html) but I'm implementing the code of the operator instead of using the operator itself, only modification is specifying `schema` in `PostgresHook`.
Airflow is running on an EC2 instance and has the `aws_default` connection defined. This is properly configured in AWS with a proper `I_AM` role, and yet I get the following error:

```
error:  S3ServiceException:The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.,Status 403,Error InvalidAccessKeyId.
```

The region is specified in the connection in the `extras` field if anyone's wondering.
I've tried solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39997714/airflow-s3-connection-using-ui) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051477/the-aws-access-key-id-does-not-exist-in-our-records) but I still keep facing this issue.
I do not want to expose the credentials in the UI or put them in a file and put them in the EC2 instance.
Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This happens not because of incorrect `AWS_CONN_ID` for the operator or setting up of the connection, rather due to a bug in the `RedshiftToS3Transfer` operator. You need to supply in `token=credentials.token`with other credentials in the unload query.

[More here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/9970)