Unable to Access an S3 Bucket From R
I have an AWS buckets with several shape files and I'm trying to connect to that bucket from R

Set environment variables
library(aws.s3)

Sys.setenv(
  "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = "",
  "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = "",
  "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" = "us-west-2"
)


name of bucket
bucket_name <- "datasci-intraday-shiny-app"


use the get bucket function
bucket_contents <- get_bucket(bucket = bucket_name, region = "us-west-2")

bucket_contents



This ends up returning the following errors.
Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?
List of 5
 $ Code          : chr "InvalidAccessKeyId"
 $ Message       : chr "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records."

  ..$ x-amz-bucket-region: chr "us-west-2"
Error in parse_aws_s3_response(r, Sig, verbose = verbose) : 
  Forbidden (HTTP 403).


In step 1, you are actually putting in your real access key and secret access key not not leaving them empty strings? Have you verified these values via other means? Can you connect to this bucket via the AWS command line tool, for example?

Yes, they are filled in and were confirmed via my SSO page. Just not putting in this pose as it'd be public

I would double check because the error message seems pretty clear: "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records". Maybe run Sys.getenv() to verify they are set correctly. Other general tips can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051477/the-aws-access-key-id-does-not-exist-in-our-records. It's going to be hard to offer any other advice without any sort of reproducible example.

would you also try paws instead of aws.s3? Can you also run readRenviron("~/.Renviron") after setting your credentials?
